# Запрет ввода в input в зависимости от value в react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook, react-hook-form

Я настроил так useForm:

```
  const {
    register,
    watch,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    setError,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm<UserSubmitForm>({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "",
      secondName: ""
    },
    mode: "onChange"
  });
```

Так у меня отрисовываются input`ы:

```
return (
    <form className="modal__form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div className="modal__body">
        <div className="modal__info">
          <TextAreaWithLimit
            register={register}
            watch={watch}
            errors={errors}
            setValue={setValue}
            setError={setError}
            name={"firstName"}
            placeholder={"Заголовок"}
            limit={50}
          />
          <TextAreaWithLimit
            register={register}
            watch={watch}
            errors={errors}
            setValue={setValue}
            setError={setError}
            name={"secondName"}
            placeholder={"Второй заголовок"}
            limit={9}
          />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" />
        <div className="modal__img">
          <img src={cardImg} alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
```

В компонент с инпутом, как видно передается значение лимита. В самом компоненте мне надо добиться следующих проверок. Require - это я сделал.

```
const TextAreaWithLimit = ({ register, watch, errors, name, placeholder, limit }: TextAreaWithLimitProps) => {
  const valueField = watch(name);
  return (
    <div className="modal__formItem">
      <textarea
        {...register(name, {
          required: { value: true, message: "Обязательное поле" },          
        })}
        readOnly={valueField.length==limit}
        rows={1}
        className="modal__textArea"
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
      <span className="modal__textArea-limit">{errors[name] ? errors[name]?.message : (limit - valueField.length)}</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Далее, мне необходимо валидировать форму по максимальному кол-ву символов. При этом мне надо останавливать ввод, если `valueField === limit` и возобновлять его, когда это условие не выполняется. Я пробовал использовать и `onChange` и `disable`. Но не могу добиться корректного выполнения скрипта. Помогите, я новичок в react hook form

Comment: Почему бы не воткнуть в textareat свойство maxLength?

Comment: Вы гений!)))))) Но что делать, если мне необходима ошибка при условии value===limit?

Comment: Там, где нужна ошибка, ведь всегда можно проверить длину и ограничение. Если внутри вашего TextAreaWithLimit можно просто сравнивать длину с ограничением, если компонентом выше, то тут уже придется вынести в стейт значения ваших эриа и максимальную длину и сравнивать. Вариантов тьма, все зависит от желаемого поведения приложения

Comment: Я хочу внутри. Желательно силами именно react hook form. Про тьму вариантов - круто, но у меня ни одна попытка не увенчалась успехом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Создаем и выводим ошибки ввода данных с помощью react-hook-form

Опишем правила, по которым мы хотим выдавать ошибки пользователю

```
{...register(name, {
  required: { value: true, message: "Обязательное поле" },
  maxLength: { value: limit, message: `Максимум ${limit} знаков` },
  minLength: { value: 1, message: `Минимум 1 знак` }
})}
```

Теперь компонент будет контролировать минимальную и максимальную длину данных в поле ввода.

Внутри компонента мы можем отслеживать изменение состояния ввода и выполнять любые действия. Допустим, сгенерируем кастомную ошибку, при помощи **setError**, о превышении некоторого количества символов(это просто пример)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (valueField.length > 3 && valueField.length < 7) {
      setError(`${name}Err`, {
        type: "custom",
        message: `${name} Пользовательская ошибка для демонстрации`
      });
    } else {
      clear();
    }
  }, [valueField]);
```

Для сброса ошибок, необходимо воспользоваться методом **clearErrors** компонента **react-hook-form**
Там где нам надо отобразить эту ошибку, добавляем вывод. Имена должны быть одинаковыми!

```
{errors[`${name}Err`] ? (
  <span>
    {errors[`${name}Err`]?.message}
  </span>
) : null}
```

Или мы можем сделать так, что бы ненужных ошибок не появлялось впринципе и всегда обрезать введенные данные пользователем до необходимой длины или выполнять любые другие преобразования по желанию

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (valueField.length > limit) {
      setValue(name, valueField.substring(0, limit));
    }
  }, [valueField]);
```

Полный код компонента на основе вашего примера

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import "./styles.css";

const TextAreaWithLimit = ({
  register,
  watch,
  errors,
  name,
  placeholder,
  limit,
  setError,
  clear,
  setValue
}) => {
  const valueField = watch(name);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (valueField.length > 3 && valueField.length < 7) {
      setError(`${name}Err`, {
        type: "custom",
        message: `${name} Пользовательская ошибка для демонстрации`
      });
    } else {
      clear();
    }
    if (valueField.length > limit ) {
      setValue(name, valueField.substring(0, limit));
    }
  }, [valueField]);

  return (
    <div className="modal__formItem">
      <textarea
        {...register(name, {
          required: { value: true, message: "Обязательное поле" },
          maxLength: { value: limit, message: `Максимум ${limit} знаков` },
          minLength: { value: 1, message: `Минимум 1 знак` }
        })}
        rows={1}
        className="modal__textArea"
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
      <br />
      <span className="modal__textArea-limit">
        {errors[name] ? errors[name]?.message : limit - valueField.length}
        {errors[`${name}Err`] ? (
          <span>
            <br />
            {errors[`${name}Err`]?.message}
          </span>
        ) : null}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {

  const {
    register,
    watch,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    setError,
    clearErrors,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "",
      secondName: ""
    },
    mode: "onChange"
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form className="modal__form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className="modal__body">
          <div className="modal__info">
            <TextAreaWithLimit
              register={register}
              watch={watch}
              errors={errors}
              setValue={setValue}
              setError={setError}
              name={"firstName"}
              placeholder={"Заголовок"}
              limit={50}
              clear={clearErrors}
            />
            <TextAreaWithLimit
              register={register}
              watch={watch}
              errors={errors}
              setValue={setValue}
              setError={setError}
              name={"secondName"}
              placeholder={"Второй заголовок"}
              limit={9}
              clear={clearErrors}
            />
          </div>
          <input type="submit" />
          <div className="modal__img">
            <img src={cardImg} alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Тестирова в [песочниче](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-banzai-xtzqnd?file=/src/App.js)